# Linux/Windows software to draw differential equation block diagrams

Tags: drawing

I need a software capable to

- **draw block diagramms for differential equations** while the software
- **must feature the style which is present in the given image**.

The software must also

- run on Linux(favorable Debian based) or Windows (XP/.../11), (32bit/64bit).
- Freeware / Any price (once/annual)

[image: img]
The image can be found [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/43716/differential-equation-and-transfer-function-of-multiple-summer-integrator-block).